# How to use com.ibm.websphere.classloader.ClassLoaderPlugin in WebSphere for instrumentation

Tags: java, websphere, instrumentation

I understood that in WebSphere it's possible to implement `com.ibm.websphere.classloader.ClassLoaderPlugin` to instrument classes. This being a different mechanism than java 1.5's `java.lnag.instrument` package.

I couldn't find any documentation about this, though.

Does anyone have a document describing this, or  a working example?

Thanks,

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

This interface is not included `WAS_HOME/dev/was_public.jar`, so I would not consider it a stable API.  I would recommend using a `-javaagent` to register a `ClassFileTransformer` instead.

Comment: you're right, of course. I'm using javaagent at the moment, but would like to use this alternative. Only that I've seen almost no documentation regarding it...